# Override wp_delete_post and move to trash instead for custom post type

Tags: hooks

The function wp_delete_post() will permanently delete when used on Custom Post Types. The `force` flag only works on `PAGE` and `POST` cpt.

> See this post as an explanation of how the force flag is being used:
>   [wp_delete_post() deletes post instead of moving it to trash](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309007/wp-delete-post-deletes-post-instead-of-moving-it-to-trash)

Question:
**A plugin I have is using this function, and I want to try hook in to wp_delete_post and move the item to trash instead of permanently deleting.**

Is it possible to use `before_delete_post` to try move things to the trash before it reaches the stage of permanently deleting?

**Alternative**:
Don't have the item deleted at all. In my case I would be happy to update the post status or some meta key and then I'll run a permanent delete on those products with that meta key at a later date.

My attempt so far - this test is simply to try see if I can prevent the full wp_post_delete from running. This did not work, the post was permanently deleted still.

```
function delete_handler($postid){
  return false;
}
add_action('before_delete_post', __NAMESPACE__.'\\delete_handler');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `wp_delete_post()` there is the following code,

```
/**
 * Filters whether a post deletion should take place.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @param bool|null $delete       Whether to go forward with deletion.
 * @param WP_Post   $post         Post object.
 * @param bool      $force_delete Whether to bypass the trash.
 */
$check = apply_filters( 'pre_delete_post', null, $post, $force_delete );
if ( null !== $check ) {
    return $check;
}
```

So I think with the following filtering you might be able to prevent the deletion.

```
function prevent_cpt_delete( $delete, $post, $force_delete ) {
  // Is it my post type someone is trying to delete?
  if ( 'my_post_type' === $post->post_type && ! $force_delete ) {
    // Try to trash the cpt instead
    return wp_trash_post( $post->ID ); // returns (WP_Post|false|null) Post data on success, false or null on failure.
  }
  return $delete;  
}
add_filter('pre_delete_post', 'prevent_cpt_delete', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Just tested and seems to work perfectly! Thanks very much.